# Strange (to me) Haskell Syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm an intermediate Haskell programmer (if you
measure by how long I've been using it, not
necessarily by skill :-) ).

I often feel like a newbie.

In looking through the Haskell Gloss sourcecode I
found some syntax I'm not familiar with.

I constructed an MWE below. 'test' is the function
in question.

I looked up the list of Haskell operators and it
says that '<-' is only used in list comprehensions
and inside a do block. This seems like neither.

It doesn't seem like a Guard since they use '=' signs
not '<-'.

It works, but what syntax is this?

Thanks in advance

```
module Main where

data Point = P Float Float

test :: Point -> Point -> Float
test pA pB 
     | (P a b) <- pA
    ,  (P c d) <- pB
     = a + b + c + d 

main :: IO()

main = do

 let x = test (P 3 11) (P 20 8)
 putStrLn $ show x

-- Yields 42.0
```

Comment: Is the acute accent (`´`) a typo?

Comment: It's called a patter guard. It's not a very commonly used construct in GHC Haskell, but sometimes it's useful to have. In your specific example, however, it's a bit useless since one could have written `test (P a b) (P c d) = a+b+c+d` instead, which is short and clear.

Comment: Thankjs everyone for the quick response! Haskell is a continuous learning experience for me.

Comment: My example was a contrived to be an MWE and it is a silly way to do it in real life.